# how to trigger function on active tab in mat-tab

Tags: angular

using angular 6 and I have 2 components I am using mat-tab and I have 3 tabs
Each tab calls a component

```
<mat-tab label="one">
<score-football ></ score-football >
</mat-tab>

<mat-tab label="second">
<score-hockey ></ score-hockey >
</mat-tab>

<mat-tab label="third">
<score-others ></ score-others>
</mat-tab>
```

How to execute or trigger a function within component, every time tab gets into focus
For example, whenever a “second” tab active, I want to trigger a function

```
getFreshScore(){
alert(‘going to get fresh score from DB’);
}
```

so each time my score get refresh

Comment: what have you tried until now?

Comment: Take a look at the [corresponding docs](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api#MatTabGroup).

Comment: tried doing with emit(true) but not worked. tried refreshing page, it worked but do not want to refresh whole page

Answer (score 1):

MatTabGroup emits an event called `selectedIndexChange` - use it.

HTML:

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedIndexChange)="getFreshScore($event)">
  <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Component:

```
getFreshScore(index: number) {
    alert('going to get fresh score from DB ' + index);
  }
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vuvmyp?file=app%2Ftab-group-basic-example.ts)

Comment: in my case, each tabs calls its own component and only tab = 2 component will have this getFreshScore function, and it should me trigger only when tab 2 got selected. I have in total 4 components, 1 create this page with tabs and rest 3 are inside tabs

Comment: if you want only `score-hockey` component to handle the focus event, you need to pass it the event. one way would be using Input\Output.

Comment: is there any thing like init() and afterinit() .. at tab level? how to track whether tab is active and if active then call some function?

Comment: you don't need `init()` .. if you want to know the state for some odd reason, just look for the class `mat-tab-label-active` on the tab itself.